# How can we add a site templates in subsites can only use the following site templates section using powershell scripts?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, site-template, sub-site

I need to add a custom site template in site settings -> page layouts & site templates for  subsites can only use the following site templates.By manuvally we can add it,how can we achieve it by using powershell scripts. please suggest some idea to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$templateNamesToKeep = "STS#0","PROJECTSITE#0","BLOG#0"

 Start-SPAssignment -Global
 $web = Get-SPWeb <URL of site> 

 # get the existing web templates from the site that will be filtered down 
 # 1033 is the locale id for English US (en-us), be sure to change to your locale 
 $existingWebTemplates = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) 
 $newWebTemplates = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplate]"

 # filter existing web templates and only keep if in the list of template names to keep 
 $newWebTemplates = $existingWebTemplates | Where-Object {$_.name -in $templateNamesToKeep} 
 $web.SetAvailableWebTemplates($newWebTemplates, 1033) 
 $web.Update() 

 Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Reference: [Set PageLayouts and Site Templates Settings in SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Set-PageLayouts-and-Site-Templates-Settings-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell)

Comment: whether we need to add the site template in ("subsites can only use the following site template section") correct me If I am wrong @BennySkogberg

Comment: @Suriya Sorry. I misunderstood your question as there where no image available...

Comment: Its okay dude, any idea to achieve this? @Benny Skogberg

Comment: @Suriya Yep - I've updated my answer!

Comment: Great, It work's like charm. Thank you so much @BennySkogberg

Comment: I have small issue in that shall we dicuss in chat

Answer (score 1):

Using below powershell script you can apply custom template to subsite.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = get-spweb https://sharepoint
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq “<Custom Templete Title>”}
$newweb = New-SPWeb -Url "https://sharepoint/newsubsite" 
$newweb.ApplyWebTemplate($template.Name)
```